# Generalization of the Lie group exponential map and its derivative

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$, and $exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ be its exponential map. The group $G$ could be finite or infinite dimensional. Let $G$ have the property that

$\bullet$ 
For each smooth curve 
$X\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R,\mathfrak g)$ there exists a curve 
$g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R,G)$ whose right logarithmic derivative is $X$, i.e.,
$$
g(0) = e, \qquad
\partial_t g(t) = T_e(\mu^{g(t)})X(t) = X(t).g(t),\quad\text{where }  \mu(a,b)=\mu_a(b)=\mu^b(a) = a.b
$$
The curve $g$ is uniquely determined by its initial value $g(0)$, if it
exists.

$\bullet$
Put $\operatorname{evol}^r_G(X)=g(1)$ where $g$ is the unique solution required above. 
Then $\operatorname{evol}^r_G: C^{\infty}(\mathbb R,\mathfrak g)\to G$ is required to be
$C^{\infty}$ also.

Note that for $X$ constant in time, $\operatorname{evol}^r_G(X)=\exp(X)$. So each regular Lie group admits an exponential mapping.

My questions are:

1) Is there any expression for the derivative of $\operatorname{evol}^r_G$. It's motivated by the fact that that there's an expression of $(Dexp)_{\mathfrak g}$ using the adjoint action on $\mathfrak g$ and derivative of the left translation in $G$.

2) Can we construct a new Lie group $H\subset = C^{\infty}(\mathbb R,G)$ with Lie algebra $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R,\mathfrak g)$ so that $\operatorname{evol}^r$ becomes the exponential map $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R,\mathfrak g)\to H$?

I must admit that I got the idea of the question from Peter Michor's answer to this question:

[Exponential map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121579/exponential-map/121611#121611)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to 1:

$TG$ is again a Lie group, semidirect product go $G$ over the normal $\mathfrak g$. See 6.7 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf). $TC^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathfrak g) = C^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathfrak g\times \mathfrak g)$. Then 
$$
T(evol_G^r) = evol^r_{TG}. 
$$
Be careful with the identifications. This is treated in detail in 38.10 of [this book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf).

Answer to 2:

See 38.11 and 42.21 of [this same second book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf).